# Does "richness" have any synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

Lexico defines "richness" as "the state of existing in or containing plentiful quantities of something desirable". However, its synonyms section includes no entries. Does anyone know any synonyms for "richness" concentrating on "quality" rather than "quantity"?

Comment: You might search for synonyms of *rich* , and convert to a noun afterward. For example, lush-->lushness, opulent-->opulence, lavish-->lavishness, robust-->robustness,fertile-->fertility.

Answer (score 1):

For quality, it's difficult because it depends on context.

Rich food can mean: with a lot of fat, with a lot of spice, and expensive. I would avoid using the word to describe food because it's frequently ambiguous.

Rich soil can mean full of nutrients, or full of humus (organic matter, not chick peas).

Rich colour would probably mean highly saturated.

The rich smell of cigars could mean that they smell expensive, that the smell is strong, or simply that the speaker/writer lickes it.

Comment: The question is about synonyms for the noun "richness", not the various meanings of the adjective "rich".

Comment: @gotube. Either you didn't read the question properly, or you do not understand that one word can have different meanings and thus require different synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched in using the "richness" keyword along with "synonym". I found a lot of words that you might want. For example,

**prosperity**

*the state of being prosperous*

**abundance**

*a very large quantity of something.*

and more . . .

Comment: I need a synonym whose concentration on richness is mostly on "quality" rather than "quantity". These two suggestions are more about quantity, right?

Comment: You didn't specify that requirement in the question. Also, the definition given does not mention anything about 'quality'.